# What are the options to draw graphs for multiple variables in a negative binomial glmm?

Tags: plot, graph, interaction, glmm

I am trying to graph plots through `plot_model` command and I was wondering if there were any other ways to graph predictions for two continuous variables (in this case-Nitro*Ph) interaction against the continuous dependent variable (Number). Also, should I model it on the log scale? Any help will be appreciated. My output summary is as follows:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
  Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: Negative Binomial(6.7816)  ( log )
Formula: 
Number ~ Nitrogen * Ph0_20 + Sodium + Rain + Flytime + Dist_water +  
    Predator + +Removals + Dist_Zebra + Dist_Browser + Dist_Wart +  
    elevation + Aspect + slope + ruggedness + NDVI + (1 | Location)
   Data: glmm1

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1082.3   1149.8   -515.1   1030.3       73 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0904 -0.6059 -0.0903  0.6094  2.9701 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Location (Intercept) 0.2061   0.454   
Number of obs: 99, groups:  Location, 9

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      5.62689    0.26423  21.295  < 2e-16 ***
Nitrogen         0.33984    0.17135   1.983 0.047338 *  
Ph0_20           0.34988    0.30301   1.155 0.248218    
Sodium          -1.20671    0.29586  -4.079 4.53e-05 ***
Rain            -0.15713    0.05183  -3.032 0.002433 ** 
Flytime         -0.03877    0.25810  -0.150 0.880584    
Dist_water       0.26310    0.09170   2.869 0.004114 ** 
PredatorYes     -4.58973    1.09371  -4.196 2.71e-05 ***
Removals        -0.05528    0.04392  -1.259 0.208132    
Dist_Zebra      -0.05227    0.06220  -0.840 0.400701    
Dist_Browser     0.09437    0.06835   1.381 0.167357    
Dist_Wart       -0.28687    0.08140  -3.524 0.000424 ***
elevation       -0.94331    0.27500  -3.430 0.000603 ***
AspectN         -0.61920    0.33577  -1.844 0.065171 .  
AspectNE        -0.75846    0.28340  -2.676 0.007445 ** 
AspectNW        -0.33357    0.27374  -1.219 0.223000    
AspectS         -0.48831    0.18371  -2.658 0.007861 ** 
AspectSE        -0.17506    0.18443  -0.949 0.342531    
AspectSW        -0.35594    0.19790  -1.799 0.072090 .  
AspectW         -0.24656    0.22394  -1.101 0.270887    
slope            0.46330    0.29578   1.566 0.117269    
ruggedness      -0.82243    0.29230  -2.814 0.004898 ** 
NDVI            -0.43618    0.07398  -5.896 3.73e-09 ***
Nitrogen:Ph0_20  0.44751    0.18505   2.418 0.015593 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This is my current code for the plot:

```
plot_model(glmm1, type = "pred", terms = c("Nitrogen","Ph0_20"))
```